# Glimpse - How do I access HttpContext.Session inside an IRuntimePolicy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, glimpse

I'm enjoying the [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com) web diagnostics platform for ASP.NET, and would like to deploy it to production to capture data about end-user interactions to help with troubleshooting. Obviously I'd like to lock down access so not just anyone can access all the data Glimpse captures.

I've implemented GlimpseSecurityPolicy (an instance of IRuntimePolicy) and confirmed via a debug breakpoint that the Execute method is invoked when I request a page on my site.

**The problem is that I can't interrogate the session associated with the current HttpContext.** I'm able to get an instance of the context by calling `policyContext.GetHttpContext()`... but that context object has a null `Session` property. The property is also null if retrieved via `HttpContext.Current`.

When accessing the current context elsewhere in my main application code (via `HttpContext.Current`), the `Session` property is populated and I can interact with it just fine.

So I have two related questions:

- Why is the `Session` property not populated?
- How can I get access to the current `Session` from inside a Glimpse IRuntimePolicy?

*If it helps, I'm running Glimpse 1.8.5 in a website running ASP.NET MVC 5.2. Also I've left the IRunTimePolicy `ExecuteOn` property returning the default `return RuntimeEvent.EndRequest | RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource;`.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that your `IRuntimePolicy` is actually being executed to late in the pipeline. As you said, you kept the default value for the `ExecuteOn` property, and the session is closed before that `RuntimeEvent`.

If you change the value for `ExecuteOn` to `RuntimeEvent.BeginSessionAccess | RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource` then the `Session` property should be available inside your `IRuntimePolicy` implementation.

Regarding the `RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource` this one is only needed if your `IRuntimePolicy` is actually used to enforce resource access aka used for Glimpse Authorization, see [this blog post](http://blog.getglimpse.com/2013/12/09/protect-glimpse-axd-with-your-custom-runtime-policy/) for more details. So if that is not the case, then you can remove it as well.

Comment: Thanks! Either `BeginSessionAccess` or `EndSessionAccess` makes the session data available. Looking at the source makes this a little more clear. (https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Extensibility/RuntimeEvent.cs)

Comment: This wasn't sufficient for me. Perhaps things have changed since 2014. 
Had to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611058/retrieve-the-session-in-the-glimpsesecuritypolicy-runtimeevent-executeresource