# Retrieve the Session in the GlimpseSecurityPolicy RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource

Tags: glimpse

Using glimpse I'm able to access the session information accept when using the `RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource`. Without this the axd file is exposed and I'd rather have it disabled unless specific users are logged in. The session will be null in both examples below. Also I've tried having the class implement `IRequiresSessionState` but that didn't help either.

```cs
namespace Glimpse
{
    public class GlimpseSecurityPolicy:IRuntimePolicy
    {
        public RuntimePolicy Execute(IRuntimePolicyContext policyContext)
        {
            try
            {
                var name = HttpContext.Current.Session["username"];
                var name2 = policyContext.GetHttpContext().Session["username"];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            // You can perform a check like the one below to control Glimpse's permissions within your application.
            // More information about RuntimePolicies can be found at http://getglimpse.com/Help/Custom-Runtime-Policy
            // var httpContext = policyContext.GetHttpContext();
            // if (!httpContext.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
            // {
            //     return RuntimePolicy.Off;
            // }

            return RuntimePolicy.On;
        }

        public RuntimeEvent ExecuteOn
        {
            // The RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource is only needed in case you create a security policy
            // Have a look at http://blog.getglimpse.com/2013/12/09/protect-glimpse-axd-with-your-custom-runtime-policy/ for more details
            get { return RuntimeEvent.EndRequest | RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to enable Glimpse only for certain user?

Comment: I was able to allow Glimpse only to certain users by configuring it in web.config. <location path="Glimpse.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="domain\username" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

Comment: And you have to disable localpolicy on glimpse  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">

    <runtimePolicies>
      <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet" />
      </ignoredTypes>
    </runtimePolicies>
  </glimpse>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that the Glimpse [`HttpHandler`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.AspNet/HttpHandler.cs) which processes the requests for Glimpse.axd does not implement the [`IRequireSessionState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx) interface.

It is that `HttpHandler` that will eventually execute all `IRuntimePolicy` instances that have `RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource` configured as part of the `ExecuteOn` property value.

I think the easiest solution for you is to create your own `IHttpHandler` that implements the `IRequireSessionState` interface and forwards all calls to the Glimpse `HttpHandler` as shown below.

```cs
public class SessionAwareGlimpseHttpHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    private readonly HttpHandler _glimpseHttpHandler = 
        new Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler();

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        _glimpseHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(context);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return _glimpseHttpHandler.IsReusable; }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to update your web.config to use that handler instead of the original one:

```xml
...
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <handlers>
        <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="YourNamespace.SessionAwareGlimpseHttpHandler, YourAssembly" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    ...
</system.webServer>
...
```

Once all this is in place, you should be able to access the `Session` inside your `IRuntimePolicy`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Great solution to the problem!

Comment: Thanks! Too bad the Glimpse documentation makes no note of this.